# When do we have to release ByteBuffer in netty5 by calling ByteBuffer.release()?

Tags: netty

Can you somebody give me a general guideline about using ByteBuffer correctly in Netty5? I don't know when I  should call release on an allocated bytebuffer? For example, i have this one:

```
 ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(String.valueOf(new Date()).getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
 ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new PingWebSocketFrame(buf));
 buf.release();
```

Do I have to call release on Unpooled bytebuffer?

Thanks,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out our documentation... Should be quite clear here:
http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html

Comment: To be honest documentation is not very clear on this. Is `wrappedBuffer` a derived one or not? Also, if it wraps a regular array, why do we need reference counting for that?